# C - Creating a new linked list from another list starting at the nth node

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to implement a droplist function that creates a new list with the elements of the input list exept the first n elements. My approach his to go trough the list and increment the counter so I know at which node I'am and start creating the new list at that node. Whats the issue here?

```
// Create a list consisting of nodes of list, except the first n.
Node* drop_list(Node* list, int n) {
    Node* result;
    int counter = 0;        //sets counter to 0
    if (counter == n ){
        Node* result = new_node(list->value, NULL); //creates the head of the note starting at the nth
        node
        for (Node* ntf = result; list->next != NULL; ntf = ntf->next) {
            
            list = list->next;                       //updates list->value
            ntf->next = new_node(list->value, NULL); //creates the rest of the new list
            
        }
        return result;
    }
    else {
        list = list->next;  //sets list value to the next node
        counter++;          //increments counter        
    }
}
```

Comment: The function invokes undefined behavior when n is not equal to 0. That is it does not do something useful.

Comment: The referred to duplicate is about the Python `yield` operator.  Completely unrelated. Voting to reopen, and/or find a better duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If `counter < n`, you will never enter the part where you copy the nodes. Note that, though you increase `counter` in the `else`-part, you leave the function afterwards.

A simple solution would be to call `drop_list` recursively in the `else`-part, e.g. like

```
}
else {
    drop_list(list->next, n-1);      
}
```

Note that you'll have to check corner cases like `list` being `NULL`, `n` being greater than the number of nodes in the list and so on. I leave this up to you.

Generally I'd prefer a solution where you move to the node in question with a loop and then start copying.

BTW: Instead of copying nodes before dropping them afterwards you could simply return the n'th node as new head of the list, could you?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is if n will be greater than zero then it will never enter if (counter == n). It will go to the else block and after doing stuff written there in the else block, it will simply return.